# Java-JDatePicker Not Displaying anything

Tags: java, datepicker

i am trying to get the date from the JDatePicker but my problem is eventhough i selected the date its not displaying in the result textbox.
here is my code
can anyone help to how to solve this problem.

```
public class Datepicker extends JFrame {Datepicker(){
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
UtilDateModel model=new UtilDateModel();
Properties p=new Properties();
p.put("text.today","Today");
p.put("text.month","Month");
p.put("text.year","Year");
JDatePanelImpl panel=new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
JDatePickerImpl datepic=new JDatePickerImpl(panel,null);
datepic.setBounds(220,350,120,30);
frame.add(datepic);
Date selectedDate=(Date)datepic.getModel().getValue();
frame.setSize(300, 300);
frame.setVisible(true);}
```

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

Please, instead of
`JDatePickerImpl datepic=new JDatePickerImpl(panel,null);`

do this as follow, it's worked for me :

```
datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new DateLabelFormatter());

public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

    private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        if (value != null) {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
            return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```